# Windows PE detemine entry point virtual address

Tags: windows, x86, portable-executable, entry-point

I am examining a Windows executable with 'PE Editor' which displays the Entry point as 0x15B8, how do we determine this entry point's address as a virtual address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry point is stored relative to the load address of the module.

The module can state its preferred address by setting the `ImageBase` field in the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` (see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985997.aspx)).  However, the OS is free to select another address, either because the preferred address is in use, or, these days, because of ASLR.

I'm not sure what environment you're running this on, but if you're doing this with a live running program: It's an implementation detail, but on NT you can cast an `HMODULE` into a pointer and that is the load address of the module.  You can also read PE headers based on that.  So for example you can add the `AddressOfEntryPoint` member to the address of the `HMODULE` and find an entry point...  If rather than load time info, you'd like something like a byte offset into the file, you'll have to parse the section headers to find where in the file it goes.

Comment: Well, I am running this on 32bit Windows 7 and using PE Editor to see the values. It shows a Entry Point of 0x15B8, Image Base of 0x400000 and base of code as 0x1000. So would that mean that the Virtual address of the entry point could be 0x400000+0x1000+0x15B8?

Comment: @user2104070 - No, it would be 0x4015B8 - base address plus entry point.  But as I mentioned, that is just what your image says is the *preferred* address; Windows could decide to load your code at another address.